# Run Batch file as administrator

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I created a batch file which stops a service,then stops a process and then starts the service it stopped.

When I execute the batch file, it says "access denied".
I cannot figure out why it says access denied because I am an Administrator.
I searched everywhere for a solution to this with no luck.

Here are my command lines within the batch file:

```
net stop uvnc_service
taskkill /f /im winvnc.exe
net start uvnc_service
```

Note: When I right click on it, I can say "run as administrator" which then works, but I created a task in task scheduler which executes the batch file every 5 minutes and I cant right click and say "run as administrator" every 5 minutes.

Also in the properties of the batch file under the compatibility tab, "run as administrator is greyed out so I cant check it.

How can I automatically run the batch file as administrator every 5 minutes?

Is there maybe a command line I can insert into my batch file that runs it as administrator every time?

Comment: You need to elevate the user access to administrator. run a cmd program tha elevates you and then run the batch.. make a wrapper batch that does both operations..

Comment: Why are you start and stopping that service every 5 minutes?

Comment: it's the UltraVNC's service and it keeps crashing after time so i'm restarting it every 5 minutes so it doesn't crash

Comment: I like adding this to the top of my files: `if not "%1"=="am_admin" (echo Loading Admin... & echo %cd%>C:\users\Public\CDT.txt & powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)` Then below that `set /p cdd=<C:\users\Public\CDT.txt`  and `cd %cdd%` . The problem is that batch files do not run as administrator unless you tell them to, regardless of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Might this help you? I assume you already have the file running every 5 minutes and just need some method of adding the right admin rights.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755553/automatically-running-a-batch-file-as-an-administrator

EDIT: You should also be able to set "run with higher privileges" in the scheduler which might solve it for you.

Comment: you assume right.

Comment: I just tried what you said and it doesn't work, here is what it says in CMD after i execute it:

Comment: oh there i cant even post it in comment, i will post it as answer

Comment: Is that with adding the admin line to the batch file or setting the higher privilege under "General" on the task scheduler?

Comment: it is with adding the admin line to the batch file. it is already set to use highest privileges in task scheduler.

Comment: So here you seem to have a syntax error with the RUNAS command. Ensure you changed the line to suit your specific account and requirements. This page will help you construct what you require. http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html

EDIT: I also noticed your spelling of Restrat.bat. Unless you have actually misspelled the actual filename to?

Comment: I did not misspell is, that's how it is in the file name. i adjusted where needed to fit my situation but still does not work. I can't understand it.

Comment: Note: while testing this, i noticed that a PC on which my batch said "access denied" earlier, now runs the batch file with no problem and i haven't installed additional programs or software. How could this have happened?

Comment: Right take the runas line from your script and return it to it's original state. Create an new batch file and use the runas line and point it at the original file. See if that works. Bit of a hack I know.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Have you tried the [MakeMeAdmin.cmd script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2005/03/11/394244.aspx) by Aaron Margosis? A great way to learn how to re-start your script with elevated privileges.
2. How about [Matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights) found at StackOverflow?

Hope that helps somewhat...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what it says in CMD after i execute it:

C:\Users\VANTO.JACQUES\Documents>runas /savecred /profile /user:Administrator VN
C Restrat.bat
RUNAS USAGE:

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred | /netonly] ]
        /user: program

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred] ]
        /smartcard [/user:] program

RUNAS /trustlevel: program

/noprofile        specifies that the user's profile should not be loaded.
                     This causes the application to load more quickly, but
                     can cause some applications to malfunction.
   /profile          specifies that the user's profile should be loaded.
                     This is the default.
   /env              to use current environment instead of user's.
   /netonly          use if the credentials specified are for remote
                     access only.
   /savecred         to use credentials previously saved by the user.
                     This option is not available on Windows 7 Home or Windows 7
 Starter Editions
                     and will be ignored.
   /smartcard        use if the credentials are to be supplied from a
                     smartcard.
   /user              should be in form USER@DOMAIN or DOMAIN\USER
   /showtrustlevels  displays the trust levels that can be used as arguments
                     to /trustlevel.
   /trustlevel        should be one of levels enumerated
                     in /showtrustlevels.
   program         command line for EXE.  See below for examples

Examples:

> runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
>   runas /profile /env /user:mydomain\admin "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
>   runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""

NOTE:  Enter user's password only when prompted.
NOTE:  /profile is not compatible with /netonly.
NOTE:  /savecred is not compatible with /smartcard.

C:\Users\VANTO.JACQUES\Documents>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Put quotes around the file name: "VNC Restart.bat"